# MultipleChoiceField not being submitted with form

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to create a custom admin interface using Django and Python as a learning experience, so I do not want to use any 3rd party apps or anything like that.

The problem arises when I (as a superuser) try and add a user. I am unable to set the user's permissions. Currently I am using a `MultipleChoiceField` to allow the adding of permissions to the new user, but the problem is that whenever I try to add the new user, I get the error message `Enter a list of values`, even though I have selected permissions. And this is also a problem when I leave the `select` field blank when I don't want the user to have any permissions.

I've tried creating a custom `MultipleChoiceField`, which is a subclass of the `MultipleChoiceField`, and then overriding the `to_python()` and `validate()` methods. I also tried accessing the data in the `clean()` method, but since the form field failed validation, it does not exist within the `cleaned_data` dictionary. I also tried to override `clean_permissions` method, but that did not work either. And in the `to_python()` method, I only seem to be receiving the last item in the `select` field.

Below is the add user form, which allows the superuser to give the new user permissions; permissions are selected in one box and then added to the one below it.
[image: Add user form]

Below is the code for the `MultipleChoiceField`

```
all_permissions = ((i+1, str(perm)) for i, perm in enumerate(Permission.objects.all()))
selected_permissions = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=all_permissions,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'multiple': ''}), required=False)
selected_permissions.validate = None
```

As you can see, I am giving each permission a number (in the `value` attribute of the HTML `option`s). And for some reason, it does not render as a multiple `select` box unless I specify the `multiple` HTML attribute directly.

Basically, I don't want django to check if the `select` is empty, but only to check if the values in the `select` are valid (as it does normally) and submit those values to the view so that I can add the necessary permissions to the user.

And because I get the error `Enter a list of values`, the form's `is_valid()` method obviously returns False.

I can access the form's `data` field, which gives me the list of selected permissions which is what I want, but the form's validation fails and the selected permissions are not in the `cleaned_data` dictionary and the error still appears on the client side.

I'm completely lost with this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you use the widget [`SelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple)?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much, Daniel!